# ngOnChanges does not trigger

Tags: angular

I prepared a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbijgr?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)(without server side code) that the reassignment of my variable does not work, when it will be delivered async from the back.

I want to reassign these values, that the objects of the array are the same type for using it in a a select-Box.

What can I do ?

Comment: Give us sample, what you tried. That helps all

Comment: ngOnChanges is triggered for @Input() changes, not for any property that resides in the component.

Comment: This question is off-topic.  => "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined by the community. What's on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, so it may be necessary to reword the question to fit this site's scope after reviewing the community guidelines."... This is not about programming ?

Answer (score 2):

ngOnChanges triggers only when (input) values changes in the component, to get the values of selection, you need to update your change method to retrieve the values such that,

You need to use (ngModelChange) in case of selected values an object,

```
(ngModelChange)="onDropdownChangeUnit($event)"
```

instead of (change) that works for primitive types,

```
 (change) = "onDropdownChangeUnit(rec,iu)"
```

Comment: Ok, but this is not triggered when the program first starts ?

Comment: when you make some changes in the selection it will get triggered.